# Where to find the statement "time series discord is the best overall technique among all techniques" in Chandola et al.(2009)?

Tags: time-series, data-mining

[Senin et al. (2015) "Time series anomaly discovery with grammar-based compression"](https://openproceedings.org/2015/conf/edbt/paper-155.pdf) claim exactly the following (copied and pasted):

> in a recent extensive empirical study by Chandola et al., where they
> concluded ”..on 19 different publicly available data sets, comparing 9
> different techniques **time series discord** is the best overall technique
> among all techniques” [3]

where

> [[3] Chandola, V., Cheboli, D., and Kumar, V., Detecting Anomalies in a Time Series Database, CS TR 09–004 (2009)](https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/215791/09-004.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y)

Then, if we go to the [Technical Report of Chandola et al. (2009)](https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/215791/09-004.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y), we can just find the following snippet:

> on 19 different publicly available data sets

but not the rest of what quoted by Senin et al. (2015). Also, we can find an apparently "different" type of conclusion (copied and pasted) in the [Technical Report of Chandola et al. (2009)](https://conservancy.umn.edu/bitstream/handle/11299/215791/09-004.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y):

> At a high level, our results indicate that none of the techniques are
> superior to others across all data sets, but have certain
> characteristics that make them effective for certain types of data
> sets, and ineffective for certain others

Could you please tell me where I can find the quote made by Senin et al. (2015) in Chandola et al. (2009)?

Comment: My first guess would be that Senin et al. (2015) didn't read Chandola et al. (2009) properly and they made a mistake in their paper (it might even have been intentional).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment @Erwan! ...the thing is that many papers cite Chandola et al. (2009) to somehow support the "time series discord"...... I think this could be misleading to researchers

Comment: it's a bit surprising if there are many papers which have this interpretation, but it's still possible that one or two authors made the mistake at some point and all the other authors didn't bother checking the paper themselves.

Comment: I was thinking about the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same citation of Chandola et al. (2009) is made by Eamonn Keogh in its [Matrix Profile Tutorial](https://www.cs.ucr.edu/%7Eeamonn/Matrix_Profile_Tutorial_Part1.pdf).

My bet is that he refers in fact to Senin et al. (2015).

Tho, I could find the original sentence in the original paper, neither.